# PHP foreach loop form is not appearing in the first row

Tags: php, wordpress

i add a form in foreach loop to delete items from database. The form is appearing in all other rows except the first row.

```
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ 
        $id = $retrieved_data->id;
        $name = $retrieved_data->name;
        $email = $retrieved_data->email;
        $phone = $retrieved_data->phone;
        $text = $retrieved_data->text;
        $delbtn = '<form action="'.admin_url('admin.php?page=example-list-table.php').'"method="post">
        <button id="'.$id.'" name="deleteq" value="'.$id.'">delete</button>            
        </form>';
     
        
        $data[] = array(
                    'id'    => $id,
                    'name'  => $name,
                    'email' =>  $email,
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'text'  => $text,
                    'delbtn' => $delbtn,
                    
                );
             
    }; 


return $data;
}
```

Comment: Could you please do `inspect element` and check what `HTML` is generated for the first row and specially for button.

Comment: What do you get with `print_r($data);`?